# How to redirect USB output?

Tags: usb

I want to connect 2 PCBs to the same USB cable switch so I can choose wich one is powered. What component should I use for the Switch? Is this possible?

```
           /--PCB1
          /
---USB---< SWITCH(ON enables PCB1, OFF enables PCB2)
          \
           \--PCB2
```

Sorry I am a complete noob in eletronics.

EDIT: I need both data AND power to be redirect to the PCBs.

Comment: Do you need to switch the data lines as well?

Comment: Yes, everything.

Comment: Are PCB1 and PCB2 both slaves? If so, why not just use a USB hub, and leave both PCBs powered and usable at all times?

Comment: Nope, just one of then can be on at a time or the "source" would recognize then at the same time and have conflicts.

Comment: Does the switch have to be manual, or electrically controlled?

Comment: Any reason you can't just use a hub?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are going to need separate devices to switch the USB D+/D- lines and power.  For the USB lines, you can use a chip like the [TS3USB221A](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/scds300c/scds300c.pdf) which will work with USB 2.0 signals (480 Mbps).  You can get it for $1.38 in singles [at Digi-Key](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/TS3USB221AQRSERQ1/296-27719-1-ND/2356140).

[image]

However the TS3USB221A won't switch the power leads.  For that, you could use two P-channel MOSFETs configured in a high-side switch configuration.

Or you could use two [TSP2530](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps2530.pdf) ICs, which are USB current-limited, power-distribution
switches.  They are available [at Digi-Key](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/TPS2530DBVT/296-34880-1-ND/3587357) for $1.63 each.

[image]

This solution is considerable cheaper than other solutions such as reed or solid-state relays.

Answer (score 0):

Much depends on which USB version. And the largest problem is that the D+ and D- signals are bi-directional.

If USB 1.1 is enough, you can probably just use a couple of analog switches and 2 P-channel FETs. Maybe even a CD4066, with the switches 2 by two paired would work.

USB-2 is another matter, -3 would be a headache with analog switches.

If the peripherals behave, you could connect them to a hub, and cut the traces to the power of each peripheral. Switch the power to each with a P-channel transistor. According to the specs, a USB peripheral should not put any data on the bus if it does not have power on the +Vcc line, so the unpowered peripheral should effectively disappear.

The switching should not be relied on to be fast - the specs allows quite a bit of capacitance on the power line.